# Dynamic pages in Wordpress, using database

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, dynamic

I'm making by myself a site and I need some help because I'm not so good... All things I learned just by google, forums and blogs. Now I'm stucked in a part of my site very hard for me.
I will ask you step by step and see if I can complete the site with your help.
Sorry if my english is not perfect, I'm Italian.

So, let's go.

I created the site with WordPress, using a theme. I changed the font (directly in the css and not using the guide because my font was not listed), i customized every part by the panel, plugin and by edit directly the code of pages.
I tell you this so you can understand my level.

If i digit "**www.mysite.com/xx**" (where "xx" is a page that not exist) it go on the 404 page error.
Well, I edited that page too (404.php in the editor of WordPress) with my personal text. I didn't touch htaccess file.

So now my first purpose come.

I want use the page error for create dynamic pages.
In this page i want to write my text and the "**xx**" word, so i must get it from the link "**www.mysite.com/xx**".

It should be easy with Java script but I don't know from where to start...
I need to put that word in a Variable because i will need to process it in a second moment.

This is my 404.php code:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying 404 pages (Not Found)
 */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <section class="content">
                    <article>
                        <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Attenzione', 'iamsocial' ); ?></h2>
                        <p><?php
                            $url1 = 'http://www.example.com';
                            esc_html_e( 'Correttore in fase di ultimazione.', 'iamsocial' ); ?></p><p><?php esc_html_e( 'Vai alla ', 'iamsocial' ); ?> <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $url1 ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'home page.', 'iamsocial' ); ?></a></p>
                    </article>
                </section>
            </div>
            <aside class="col-md-3">
                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
            </aside>
        </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The part of the database is on the next question.
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you want to dynamically create the pages that does not exist through the 404.php template?

Comment: Yes yes exatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Javascript for this. You can do it in PHP with:

```
$path = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

That will return the "xx" part of the URL.

If you only need the last part of the URL, like Steven says, you can explode by / and get the last element:

```
// URL = site.com/page/xx
$page = explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); // = /page/xx
$lastEl = end($page); // = xx
```

Comment: If the URL is www.mysite.com/subpage/xx then `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will return /subpage/xx and not just xx. You then have to split the string by '/' and retrieve the last array element. Doing this with PHP makes it easier to use this variable for whatever afterwards.

Comment: Right, I just figured he meant "the part after the root path". Since he wants to display the wrong path, maybe he needs the whole thing.

Comment: Very thank you "ishegg" and "Steven", it was easy, but i never used PHP.
I need only the part after the root path, so the "ishegg" solution is very good.
Now I try and I will ask you the other part of my work. Again thank you.

Comment: Yes yes, it works very good.
If I used the first council it returned me the "xx" part of the url with the "/".
So I used the two lines of code and it return me just the "xx" word.

Comment: Awesome! Remember to accept this answer if it helped you.

Comment: Of course, done.
Now with the second part of my request i can answer here or create a new question?

Comment: It’s best to create a new question. Keeps everything better organized.

Comment: Ok I will, thank you so much.
Now i'm going to work, later i will post the new question.
I already understand you are one of the number one here :D:D:D
Thank you, bye bye